# How can I get Auth::user() to return the user created using a factory in a test?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I am working with Laravel 8.25. I have a Service class that has the following method:

```
public function getUsersBusinessManagers()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->id;

    return $user->businessManagers;
}
```

My test for this method is:

```
public function testCorrectBusinessManagersRetrievedForUser()
    {
        $user = User::factory()
            ->hasAttached(
                BusinessManager::factory()->count(1),
                ['user_fb_bm_id' => 'test']
            )
            ->create();
    
        $businessManagerService = new BusinessManagerService();
        $usersBusinessManagers = $businessManagerService->getUsersBusinessManagers();


        $this->actingAs($user)->assertEquals($user->businessManagers()->first()->id, $usersBusinessManagers->first()->id);
}
```

When running the test, how can I get `Auth:user()` in my service class to return the user I create in my test? Currently `Auth:user()` is null when I run the test.

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Did my answer help your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actingAs()` is used for the `Laravel` test web server, i would assume you could just login in the user.

```
Auth::login($user);
```